# NSMutableDictionary returning null

Tags: ios, nsmutabledictionary

I created an `NSMutableDictionary` in `NSObject` class like

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSMutableDictionary<NSNumber *, NSString *> *requestComments;
```

and saved the data in this variable when comes through API.

But when I am sending the key to get the value it is returning null every time.

To get the value I am doing like this

```
NSLog(@"%@",dataManager.requestComments[serviceRequest.RequestId]);
// serviceRequest.RequestId is returning NSNumber.
```

the output I'm getting is `"(null)"`

if I use to like this then it returns a value

```
NSLog(@"%@",[dataManager.requestComments valueForKey:@"30221"]);
```

Why it is returning null in the above case.

Comment: can you show your `requestComments` please print in log and Attach in Question

Comment: it is just printing "2017-07-06 12:45:31.071 WorkForApp[6076:96649] (null)"

Comment: What is the output for `[dataManager.requestComments objectForKey:serviceRequest.RequestId]`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on your question, this should work

```
NSLog(@"%@",dataManager.requestComments[[serviceRequest.RequestId stringValue]]);
```

Because you gave the key as `NSString` and you are expecting it to return based on an `NSNumber`. You need to look at the code which you are using to store this dictionary.

**Update**

You have mentioned that key is of `NSNumber` type. But you are passing a string in `valueForKey` and getting a valid object back. You should check how you are forming this dictionary from API response.

Comment: but as i mentioned  key for this mutable dictionary is NSNumber. Converting to string will give an error.

Comment: Then check how you are storing to the dictionary. Are you using NSNumber type as key or NSString? Without any code, it is difficult to say.

Comment: Also can you print serviceRequest.RequestId and dataManager.requestComments in two NSLogs and add to the question?

Answer (score 1):

Because you declared `requestComment` to be a`NSDictionary` which keys are `NSNumbers` and values are `NSString` doesn't oblige it to respect it.

Sample:

```
_requestComments = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];

[_requestComments setObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:34] forKey:@"54"]; // => Warning: Incompatible pointer types sending 'NSNumber * _Nonnull' to parameter of type 'NSString * _Nonnull'

id obj = [NSNumber numberWithInt:35];
id key = @"55";
[_requestComments setObject:obj forKey:key];

NSLog(@"[_requestComments objectForKey:@\"55\"]: %@", [_requestComments objectForKey:@"55"]); //Warning: Incompatible pointer types sending 'NSString *' to parameter of type 'NSNumber * _Nonnull'
NSLog(@"[_requestComments objectForKey:@(55)]: %@", [_requestComments objectForKey:@(55)]);
```

Logs:

```
$>[_requestComments objectForKey:@"55"]: 35
$>[_requestComments objectForKey:@(55)]: (null)
```

Okay, I used `id` to lure the compiler, but `id` is a common returned "class", in `objectAtIndex:`, etc. It's common in JSON parsing when you think a object will be a `NSString` but is in fact a `NSNumber` of (inverse).

Before doing `requestComments[serviceRequest.RequestId]`, enumerate ALL the keys value & class and ALL objects value & class. You can check it like this:

```
for (id aKey in _requestComments)
{
    id aValue = _requestComments[aKey];
    NSLog(@"aKey %@ of class %@\naValue %@ of class %@", aKey, NSStringFromClass([aKey class]),aValue, NSStringFromClass([aValue class]));
}
```

Then you can try to track where you put a wrong key (class).